# Parse multipart/form-data response in salesforce

Tags: apex, httpresponse

I want to parse multipart/form-data response in salesforce using apex, my response sample is below. do I need to parse it with some algorithm or there is any built-in library or method available.

```
----------fffjg902hegoj2b0efh012hf-g023rhg92gev092getfh208rhd102-----
Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ABC"; filename="ABC"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE DO_UNDERWRITE_RESPONSE SYSTEM "DewriteRes_v9_7.dtd">
<DO_UNDERWRITE_RESPONSE CaseIdentifier="89454949" InstitutionIdentifier="23423423">
    <STATUS _Condition="PROCESSED" _Name="SBAWF9.3" _Description="jdhaljdsl ajskl djalks jdlajksd" _Code="8"/>
    <_RECOMMENDATION _Code="87" AIndicator="6" BIndicator="15" RecommendationDescription="dont"/>
</DO_UNDERWRITE_RESPONSE>

----------fffjg902hegoj2b0efh012hf-g023rhg92gev092getfh208rhd102-----
Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="STATUS"; filename="STATUS"

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
XYZ Application Warnings 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 


Credit Log
----------

                    Unknown Report Retrieval Log
                    ================================

Date:  11/19/2021 10:44:17.717
User:  NYYHHHQQQQ

SSN        Requested                  Joint/
           NYYHHHQQQQ                 Acdb
=========  =========================  =======   
111111111  MMMMMMXXNNNNNN            I                             


Credit agency ZZZZ's performance time was 0 seconds.


Import Log
----------

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Casefile Support Service Results File
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Command:  XXXXXXX
UserID:     xxYYYZZ
InstID:     10101
Date:     11/19/2021 10:44:16.999
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

----------fffjg902hegoj2b0efh012hf-g023rhg92gev092getfh208rhd102-----
```

Answer (score 0):

this requirement seems to be a combination of both an inbuilt class AND some manual efforts from your end! The file needs to be first delivered into a JSON form, and then use the in-built BLOB processing class to convert it into the apex-parsable data.

http://www.fishofprey.com/2017/04/steps-required-to-support-posting.html

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_blob.htm

Would not comment without looking at detailed design of your underlying apex class.